# Modify aria-checked in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

So I have the following code on my component:

```
<template>
    <div aria-checked="false" >
        <span></span>
    </div>
</template>
```

And I need to change the aria-checked to true or false when I click. I've tried referencing it with a prop like

```
<template>
    <div aria-checked="{{ this.ariaStatus }}" @click="methodChangeAria">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</template>

props: {
            ariaStatus: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        }
```

But the props cannot be changed so I'm not sure how to follow with it.

Thanks!

Comment: one of the issues is that you {{ interpolate }} into an attribute (which is invalid syntax) instead of usin v-bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not binding it. It's supposed to be used like this:

```
<template>
  <div :aria-checked="value" >
    <span></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand